# L2TP VPN server only for DNS

Tags: linux, vpn, internal-dns, l2tp

I am trying to figure out a way to bypass my ISP's DNS hijacking, by attempting to replicate a Smart VPN solution.
Is there a way I could set up a Linux L2TP server that does not forward traffic, but only lets DNS requests go through?

Answer (score 0):

Normally a VPN is not about allowing or disallowing certain traffic but the VPN server could deploy a firewall to prevent unwanted traffic from coming out of the VPN.

It's important to not enable forced VPN usage this would route all your traffic trough the VPN which is not what you want.

For the DNS part you could push some static routes or change the DNS server adres.

To keep it simple just install a recursive DNS server on the VPN server and and configure this as your DNS server, this way you do not need to setup IP Forwarding (and NAT).